# Rundeck not able to login to Jira with credentials provided

Tags: jira, rundeck

I have Rundeck community edition 4.1. I want to include jira issue ID in my job execution. For that I installed plugsins and the jira issue exists is hwoing up in workflow step.
I configured
`project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.login=username project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.password=password project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.url=https://jiratestuser.atlassian.net` in `project.properties` file.
When I execute rundeck job, it is giving this error

```
Execution failed: 37321 in project Project-Name: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=PluginFailed: login is required}, status: failed]
```

So I configured in `framework.properties` file with below settings

`jira.url=https://instance.atlassian.net jira.login=user jira.auth_token=keys/jira/token`

I restarted rundeck service and ran the job still it gave same error.
Can someone suggest whether I am missing any?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? could you check that (and version) on the rundeck libext directory?

Comment: It is showing as `jira-notification.jar and jira-workflow-step.jar` in rundeck libext directory. But when I check on UI, it is showing as `version1.0.1`.
After installing these plugins I could see option in workflow steps with name `JIRA Issue Exists` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [reproduced](https://imgur.com/a/6cCmL1b) your issue and that happens when the plugin can't find the credentials in the right place.

#### Jira Notification

Considering that you're using the [OSS Jira Notification](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jira-notification) plugin. Follow these steps (*the first  step is optional if you don't have the plugin installed in your Rundeck instance*):

1. Install the plugin via the Plugin Manager (Gear Icon > Plugins > Find Plugins > Put "Jira" on the "Search for..." field, and install the Jira Notification Plugin).
2. You do not need to generate a "project.properties" file because that configuration is now saved on the Rundeck backend. So, log in to Rundeck and navigate to your Project > Project Settings (left menu) > Edit Configuration > Edit Configuration File button (top right). This is the "new" project's properties. There is where you need to insert your Jira credentials, such as:

```
project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.login=user
project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.password=password
project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.url=http://jira_host:port
```

3. Save the config and now run your job with THE Jira notification included in the notification tab. I used the following job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 37362a27-3e3e-4ea8-950e-ae64e2463172
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JiraNotificationJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  notification:
    onsuccess:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          issue key: RUN-23
        type: JIRA
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        adhocRemoteString: echo "hi"
      nodeStep: true
      type: exec-command
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 37362a27-3e3e-4ea8-950e-ae64e2463172
```

4. Check the Jira issue [updated](https://imgur.com/a/uHDEVte).

As you see and [according to the documentation](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jira-notification?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration), you don't need that `framework.properties` credentials. It works with the project configuration parameters.

### Jira Workflow Step

Considering that you're using the [OSS Jira Workflow Step plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jira-workflow-step) plugin. Follow these steps (*the first  step is optional if you don't have the plugin installed in your Rundeck instance*):

1. Install the plugin via the Plugin Manager (Gear Icon > Plugins > Find Plugins > Put "Jira" on the "Search for..." field, and install the Jira Workflow Step Plugin).
2. You do not need to generate a "project.properties" file because the configuration is now saved on the Rundeck backend (from Rundeck 3.1; you are using Rundeck 4.1). So, sign in to Rundeck and navigate to your Project > Project Settings (left menu) > Edit Configuration > Edit Configuration File button (up to right). That is the "new" project, properties. There is a place where you should enter your Jira credentials, like this:

```
project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.login=user
project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.password=password
project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.url=http://jira_host:port
```

3. Save the config and now run your job with the Jira Workflow Step included in your workflow. I used the following job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 93990eea-df5f-446a-beb0-5e7bb4b0bfcf
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JiraIssueExists
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        issue-key: RUN-23
      nodeStep: false
      type: JIRA-Issue-Exists
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 93990eea-df5f-446a-beb0-5e7bb4b0bfcf
```

4. Check the Rundeck execution [result](https://imgur.com/a/tk8WHqS).

Like the Notification plugin and [according to the documentation](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jira-workflow-step?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration), you don't need the `framework.properties` credentials. It works with the project configuration parameters.

Comment: Thank you. Its working but this time its giving error `[Workflow result: , step failures: {1=JiraIssueNotFound: Issue key "HX-450".}, status: failed]`
But that issue exists in Jira dashboard. Do we need to have admin access on Jira to get Jira Issue details? I am a member in this particular Jira project where this story exists and I have all access to this Project. But when I run from Rundeck, its giving this error.

Comment: My configuration is like this 
`project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.login=myemailid
project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.password=password
project.plugin.WorkflowStep.JIRA-Issue-Exists.url=https://aetest.atlassian.net/`

Comment: Could you test with another account? It seems related to your profile, or this weird issue: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jira-workflow-step/issues/1

Comment: I checked with account having full admin access as well. It was giving same error. `[Workflow result: , step failures: {1=JiraIssueNotFound: Issue key "HX-450".}, status: failed]`

Comment: Please open a new question by sharing your "project.properties" and the rundeck-config.properties file, also share a job definition example to test. (Remember that the credentials on the framework.properties aren't necessary).